# JavaFx IllegalAccessError when I launch the application from the main method of the application class and use fxmloader

Tags: java, javafx

I am using JavaFx 11 and gradle for javafx modules when I start the application from different class other than the application class itself everything is working fine, but I want to start the application in the main class of the Application class and then create the stage in a different one. This is my working example

Main class from which I am calling launch:

```
public class RestaurantApplication{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(StageManager.class, args);
    }
}
```

Application class:

```
public class StageManager extends Application {

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        currentStage = initializeFirstLoginStyle(primaryStage);
    }

    private Stage initializeFirstLoginStyle(Stage stage) throws IOException {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/FXML/login-first.fxml"));
        Pane root = loader.load();
        ...
    }
}
```

With this approach everything is working, but when I try to start the application in the same class as the Application one it gives me Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper (in unnamed module @0x71d2156a) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.util.Utils (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.util to unnamed module @0x71d2156a
at com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper.<clinit>(FXMLLoaderHelper.java:38)
```

This is the error approach:

Main class which is now the Application start which is calling another class to create my stage:

```
public class RestaurantApplication extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        StageManager stageManager = new StageManager();
        stageManager.initializeStages(primaryStage);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

}
```

Stage class:

```
public class StageManager extends RestaurantApplication {
    public void initializeStages(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        currentStage = initializeFirstLoginStyle(primaryStage);
        currentStage.show();
    }

    private Stage initializeFirstLoginStyle(Stage stage) throws IOException {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/FXML/login-first.fxml"));
        Pane root = loader.load();
        ...
```

Also my gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.7'
}
group 'fda'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180813'
    compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'org.kohsuke', name: 'github-api', version: '1.93'
    compile group: 'com.1stleg', name: 'jnativehook', version: '2.1.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.3'
    testCompile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.6.1'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.9.8'


}
javafx {
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml', 'javafx.media' ]
}
```

The same error is present even if I try to create the stage in the Application class:

```
public class RestaurantApplication extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/FXML/login-first.fxml"));
        Pane root = loader.load();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

}
```

So the only approach that works is if I call another class in the launch(). But overall it should work both ways. Is that a gradle bug?

Comment: I'm guessing you need to add `javafx.graphics` to the list of [`javafx`] modules in your _gradle_ file, as in: `modules = [ 'javafx.graphics', 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml', 'javafx.media' ]`

Comment: @Abra I've already tried and it didn't work, but I don't see the logic to work in the first way with the config I have, but to give error in the second where it is also supposed to work.

Comment: Can you try using version `0.0.8` of the `org.openjfx.javafxplugin` plugin?

Comment: @slaw I tried that also didn't work I read that it is a java thing after java 9 that is requring the Application class to be a named module and that the first way is a workaround. The exception does not appear in a jar and a gradle task tho.

Comment: Well the error means that `javafx.fxml` is not being used from the module-path. But you're using the `org.openjfx.javafxplugin` plugin which should be handling everything for you, so I don't understand how you're getting that error. If you're not already using the latest version of Gradle (currently 6.2.2), could you try updating to see if it helps?